# Create a dynamic table in dynamic SQL and reference it outside of dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the code below:

```
select top 1 * into #dbusers from dbusers

declare @tsql as varchar(1000)
set @tsql = 'select * from #dbusers'
exec (@tsql)
```

This works as I would expect i.e. one row is returned by the dynamic SQL.  Is it possible to do this:

```
declare @tsql as varchar(1000)
set @tsql = 'select top 1 * into #dbusers from dbusers'
exec (@tsql)

select * from #dbusers
```

Here I get the error:

> Invalid object name '#dbusers'

Is there a workaround?

I realise that you can have output parameters with dynamic SQL.  However, I also know that when using stored procedures you cannot return tables as output parameters.

Is it possible to do this? Is there a workaround (except creating a physical table)?

Comment: You can create a gloval temp table using ## and use two strategies to avoid collisions with other sessions: give the table a unique name (guid for example) or include spid/user name as a PK column.

Comment: Is table valued function an option?

Comment: Maybe solve the real problem first: why do you need to create a #temp table in dynamic SQL in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary tables are only available within the session that created them.  With Dynamic SQL this means it is not available after the Dynamic SQL has run.  Your options here are to:

1. Create a global temporary table, that will persist outside your session until it is explicitly dropped or cleared out of TempDB another way, using a double hash: `create table ##GlobalTemp`
   *Because this table persists outside your session, you need to make sure you don't create two of them or have two different processes trying to process data within it.  You need to have a way of uniquely identifying the global temp table you want to be dealing with.*
2. You can create a regular table and remember to drop it again afterwards.
3. Include whatever logic that needs to reference the temp table within the Dynamic SQL script

For your particular instance though, you are best off simply executing a `select into` which will generate your table structure from the data that is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to global temp tables.  +1.